# SQL Server Error: 'BETWEEN ... FOLLOWING AND CURRENT ROW' is not a valid window frame and cannot be used with the OVER clause.'?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am trying to sum 3 months' net value with the one months' net values. The code

```
SELECT [CMONTH]
      ,[ID]
      ,[NET_VALUE_1M]
      ,SUM(CAST([NET_VALUE_1M] as float)) OVER 
          (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [CMONTH] 
             ROWS BETWEEN 3 FOLLOWING AND CURRENT ROW) as 'NET_VALUE_3M'   
  FROM [Channel_AGG]
```

is firing the error

```
Msg 4193, Level 16, State 4, Line 2
'BETWEEN ... FOLLOWING AND CURRENT ROW' is not a valid window frame 
and cannot be used with the OVER clause.
```

Why, what is causing this and how to solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use

```
ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 3 FOLLOWING
```

[The upper bound cannot be smaller than the lower bound.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql)